# Wordpress - wp admin table row actions

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making custom plugin to display new table in wp-admin from database. The point of this table is that database has two tables - a table and b table. They are both connected by id. In main table I want to display a table information - Order_id, User_id, Customer, Name surname... This part I manage to do, but I want to add row action view, which would be directed to single view, where it would display information from table B which is with same order_id

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32wsU.png) - basically when I would press view it would redirect to another page and would get data from table B with order_id 14.

```
 public function register()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'my_admin_menu') );

    }
    
    public function customerview_admin_page(){
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Customer Details</h2>
        <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wpel_dalisima_orders ORDER BY order_id DESC;");
        echo "<table class='widefat fixed'>";
        echo "<th>Order_id</th>";
        echo "<th>User_id</th>";
        echo "<th>Customer</th>";
        echo "<th>Name Surname</th>";
        echo "<th>Company name</th>";
        echo "<th>Address</th>";
        echo "<th>Phone number</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>Delivery_address</th>";
        foreach($orders as $order){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$order->order_id."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$order->user_id."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$order->customer."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$order->name_surname."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$order->company_name."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$order->address."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$order->phone_number."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$order->email."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$order->delivery_address."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    

    public function my_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('My Page Title', 'My Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'my-menu', 'my_menu_output' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Submenu Page Title', 'Whatever You Want', 'manage_options', 'my-menu' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Submenu Page Title2', 'Whatever You Want2', 'manage_options', 'my-menu2', array($this, 'customerview_admin_page'));

    }
```

This is current code. How can I exactly add this view action button and redirect it to another page? Couldn't find any information that would help..

Comment: Are you using a WP_List_Table or your own thing? It seems the latter.

Comment: My own thing, but didn't quite find information how to add view button with wp list table either..

Comment: WP_List_Table is powerful but if you ever use it, you should probably read the [eleven page tutorial](https://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/). If it is your own, you just need to pass an ID of some sort, probably in the query string, from one page to the other.